# Terraform Error: Cycle: azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.stg

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

**unable to attach service_endpoint_policy_ids to the subnet**

service_endpoints created successfully but storage policy unable to attach to subnet

Ended up with below error

```
Error: Cycle: azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.stg, azurerm_subnet.backend, module.storage_bsai.var.vnet_subnet_id (expand), module.storage_bsai.azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount_name, module.storage_bsai.output.id (expand)
```

**provider**
azurerm version = "2.65.0"

Terraform resource for storage policy and subnet

```
  resource "azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy" "stg" {
  name                = "storage-policy-bsai"
  resource_group_name = "${var.env}-bsai"
  location            = var.region
  definition {
    name        = "storage"
    #description = "definition1"
    service_resources = [
      module.resource_group.id,
      module.storage_bsai.id
    ]
  }
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  depends_on           = [module.vnet]
  name                 = "backend"
  virtual_network_name = "${var.env}-${var.region}-bsai"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.env}-bsai"
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
  service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage", "Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB", "Microsoft.ServiceBus", "Microsoft.Web", "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry"]
  service_endpoint_policy_ids = [azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.stg.id]
  delegation {
    name = "delegation"
    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue -
This appears that you have a cyclic dependency in your config? (i.e. where 2 or more resources depend on each other, meaning Terraform cannot reconcile what needs to happen in what order)

```
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12593#issuecomment-881192611
```

Answer (score 0):

`service_endpoint_policy_ids` should be a list:

```
service_endpoint_policy_ids = [azurerm_subnet_service_endpoint_storage_policy.stg.id[
```

Comment: even with the list also not working @Marcin